# Cronjob not working as before

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to fix a cron job that suddenly stopped working. This is my cron job:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://example.com?update_feedwordpress=1
```

After my boss did some configurations on the server and rebooted, the feeds stopped updating.
I have verified that cron is running on the server, I even set up a test cron job which worked fine:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /home/user/logs/cron-logs.txt
```

I have also checked `syslog` file and here's a sample of the output I see repeatedly:

```
Jan  6 09:00:01 ip-172-31-11-201 CRON[2781]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/curl --silent ttp://example.com?update_feedwordpress=1 )
Jan  6 09:00:01 ip-172-31-11-201 CRON[2780]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I guess cron is tring to send mail but there's no MTA installed on the server and I would rather log errors to a file[Not sure how to do that though:)].
Please, any help on this would be great.

I finnally got to write the output to a file by doing this:

/usr/bin/curl http://example.com?update_feedwordpress=1 >> /home/user/logs/cron.txt

and this was the output I got:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100     4  100     4    0     0     36      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    37
```

I'm not sure what it means though, I was expecting an error message.

Comment: what kind of changes did your boss? You can find some debugging infos in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: Have you tried removing `--silent` and redirecting to a log file, as you did in your second example?

Comment: @fedorqui He disabled source/destination checks

Comment: @Phylogenesis I tried this earlier: (user) CMD (/usr/bin/curl --silent http://example.com?update_feedwordpress=1 >/home/user/logs/cron-log.txt 2>/home/logs/cron-err.txt. It didn't work

Comment: It still doe not work without the --silent

Comment: Your latest edit suggests that the response from the URL is just 4 bytes. I assume this isn't what you're expecting. Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes the url is correct, but turns out the actual feed url in my wordpress site was broken and that's why the feeds were not updating. The problem was not from my cron job. Thanks for all your help:)

Comment: @user3795016 We indicated you to eliminate de `--silent` option because it will probably make the command to output something that allow you to make a diagnostic.  You are not helping us too much to help you :)  If you are not understanding what we say, perhaps you'd better to tell your boss to switch system administrator for this system.

Comment: Have you notice that the url in the CRON log doesn't have the `h` of `http://...` ???  Have you mispelled the url?